# Get visible size and poision of QGraphicsVideoItem

Tags: c++, qt, video

I've added `QGraphicsVideoItem` in `QGraphicsScene` of `QGraphicsView`. I use

```
_graphicsView->fitInView(_scene->sceneRect(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
```

to resize the video itself. It changes it's size and position, but I can't get thier actual values.

```
qDebug() << "***";
qDebug() << _graphicsView->sceneRect();
qDebug() << _scene->itemsBoundingRect();
qDebug() << _scene->sceneRect();
qDebug() << _item->boundingRect();
qDebug() << "***";
```

returns same values

```
***
QRectF(0,13.3333 320x213.333)
QRectF(0,13.3333 320x213.333)
QRectF(0,13.3333 320x213.333)
QRectF(0,13.3333 320x213.333)
***
```

How do I get visible position and size of the video in the view?